# How do you automatically start my ruby sinatra program when windows server boots?

Tags: ruby, windows, sinatra

I have a simple sinatra program that is written in ruby that needs to load automatically when my Windows Server 2008 loads. At first, put it under Start -> Programs -> Startup which loads fine, but it seems the program will only load if I log in as a user. Same with the registry entry: HKLM -> Software -> Windows - Run. I would like the program to start at bootup.

What is the best way to do this? I keep on seeing I shold create a "service" for it, but it seems very complex to a non-windows person. Is there a simpler way to get what I want done? It's a simple, non-critical program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [win32-daemon](https://github.com/djberg96/win32-service) gem.

[Here](https://github.com/pfeilbr/ruby-windows-service-example) is an example of usage: subclass the `Daemon` class that will `run` your Sinatra app, and use `Service#create` to install your new daemon.